# How do i input an array to a Map Reduce Job?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I have a service that is continuously retrieving some data .I am dumping this data into an array, this data has to be further processed. Is it possible to create a dynamic array that keeps getting updated by serivice, and side by side i can execute the Map Reduce Job?
Also how what class do i use to simply take an array input(instead of a file) ?
PS I'm new to Hadoop/Map Reduce
I'm coding in Java.

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop is for batch processing, so it's powerful only when you have stored data like files and it needs to be processed and the job finishes. You might have a look at [Storm](http://storm-project.net/). I think it will suit your use case better.